# Realm Sync data resets on app reinstall

Tags: ios, realm

I have an iOS app which uses Realm locally and it works great, and my intention is to use Realm Object Server to enable:

- Data sync across devices
- Data restoration on app reinstall

I've been having a lot of trouble with the last one. The flow in my app is the following:

1. First, it tries to find a `User` in my Realm Sync. If a `User` exists, go to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 2;
2. Ask for the user's name, income and payday;
3. Get the user's userRecordID for iCloud and `logIn` to Realm Object Server.
4. Use the SyncUser's `identity` as the `User` entity identifier. Save the data I just asked (name, income and payday) to Realm;
5. Go to main app screen and let the user enjoy the app.

ROS is using cloudkit based authentication. The problem occurs if I follow steps 1-4 above, and then reinstall the app. I expected the previously created `User` to be retrieved in step 1, but instead all of its fields beside the primary key are set to blank values (name becomes empty string, income and payday become 0). Is this behavior expected? Is what I want to do within the purpose of Realm?

## EDIT

Made the flow clearer after @AustinZ's answer.

Comment: Try checking against the getters instead of the fields directly

Comment: Do you mean like `[user getName]`? I'm using Swift, is there a way for me to do that? Furthermore, I just noticed that the user entry back in the Realm Object Server seems to have its values set to blank values as well (I'm looking through Realm Studio).

Comment: Hmm..not sure then. I'm not that well versed in sync

Answer (score 2):

"Data restoration on app install" is definitely a valid use case for Realm Sync. However, the flow you describe is problematic.

A synchronized Realm is identified by two pieces of information: a sync user and the Realm's path on the Realm Object Server (e.g. `/~/my/realm`). If you have the same sync user logged into multiple devices, and they each open a copy of a Realm at the same path, they are opening the same synced Realm and will stay in sync with each other.

However, to get the same sync user, a user needs to *log in* to the Realm Object Server from their device. You do this by creating a CloudKit `SyncCredentials` value using `SyncCredentials.cloudKit(token:)` and passing that credential to `SyncUser.logIn()`. The device will then communicate with the Realm Object Server, and if the log in succeeds, then the `logIn()` method's callback block will be invoked and will give you a `SyncUser`. That is the sync user you need to use to open Realms.

So:

- You shouldn't be saving users or user info to Realms manually. We persist the relevant information automatically.
- If a user deletes and re-installs their app, the app's documents and files are deleted as well, which means you shouldn't assume you can access a Realm's data after the app which created it was re-installed.
- What you should be doing is, in step 3, using the user's CloudKit credentials and logging into the Realm Object Server as described above.

Please review our [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#users) for more information.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot to state that I do `logIn` during step 3. the `User` entity I mentioned was conceived to store additional data (in this case, name, income and payday). Not anything auth-related. But I'm really curious about the second bullet point you stated there. I cannot assume that? Then I guess Realm is not the best option for me.

Comment: You can't assume a _local_ (offline) Realm's files are still present, obviously because a local Realm is just like any other on-disk file, and those files are deleted when your app is uninstalled.

When you open a _synced_ Realm though, the remote copy will be downloaded from the server so they will have all the data they had before they uninstalled the app.

Comment: Of course, it's obvious. The problem I'm having is that the User seems to be downloaded, but its fields have blank values in them. Can it be related to default values I have set in my code? It doesn't really make a lot of sense, but just in case...

Comment: If you need detailed help with a specific project of yours, you're welcome to post a ticket at our GitHub (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues) and get more personalized attention. If you do so, please be prepared to show the relevant code and a sample project, if applicable.